# Conditional filtering in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a data frame and am trying to use conditional formatting.

After running the sample code below (producing data frame X):

```
x <- data.frame(A = c("A","A","A", "B","B", "B"), B = c("X","Y", "Z", "X", "K","N"), C = c(20,30,40,40,10,50))
```

I have 2 variables A and B in column A and a total of 6 rows (3 each for A and B).

Variable A's corresponding values are X, Y, Z in Column B and 20, 30, 40 numbers in Column C. Similarly Variable B's corresponding values are X, K, N in Column B and 40, 10, 50 in Column C.

I want to select only (between A and B in this example), that which contains X and 20 together. So in this case, as Variable A has one of its values as X in Column B and 20 in Column C, I want my resultant data frame to only contain variable A and all its corresponding values. However, since variable B contains X but "not" 20 (corresponding value to X is 40 here), I don't want to keep B.

Please refer to the resultant data frame as produced by the second code below (producing data frame Y).

```
y <- data.frame(A = c("A","A","A"), B = c("X","Y", "Z"), C = c(20,30,40))
```

Would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `any` in `filter` after doing a `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   group_by(A) %>%
   filter(any(B == 'X' & C == 20))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   A [1]
#  A     B         C
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#1 A     X        20
#2 A     Y        30
#3 A     Z        40
```

---

Or we can `sum` the logical vector

```
x %>% 
   group_by(A) %>%
   filter(sum(B == 'X' & C == 20) > 0)
```